# Remove all occurrences of dot, except for the first occurence in the elements of a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list that I need to convert to floats. As the data is not inputted by me, there are elements that have an accidental extra period, for example `39.04.1450`. I need to be able to **automatically** remove all of the periods except for the first one that appears so that I don't get an error when I say `list=float(list)`.

Sample list:

```
latitude= [' -86.57', ' 39.04.1450', ' 37.819' ,' 45.82', ' 54.42', ' 0.' ,' 53.330444',
  ' +45.75' ,' 52.36', ' 43.2167', ' -36.75', ' 6.8N' ,' 40.833' ,' -97.981',
  ' 41.720', ' 41.720', ' 37.41' ,' 37.41' ,' 37.41', ' 37.41']
```

As you can see, `latitude[1]` has an extra decimal point. Of course, I will also need to strip the N in `6.8N` but that is a separate problem.

Comment: What about the leading spaces?

Comment: what about `' 6.8N'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj `float` and `int` ignore leading/trailing space

Comment: @Solar are you sure you are reading in the list correctly?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, they don't ignore `N's` though ;)

Comment: @Solr, no matter what you do `float(list)` is not going to work

Comment: This kind of automatic error correction seems problematic. When the user types "1.2.3", how do you know whether they meant "1.23" or "12.3"? I recognize that "39.04.1450" can't be 3904.1450, because latitude doesn't go that high, but other ambiguous inputs might exist.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this:

```
def fix_float(s):
    return s.replace('.', '[DOT]', 1).replace('.', '').replace('[DOT]', '.')
```

The function replaces the first occurrence of `'.'` with `'[DOT]'`. Then, it removes all the ocurrences of `'.'`. Finally, it replaces `'[DOT]'` back to `'.'`.

To apply it to all the elements of your list, write:

```
fixed_latitudes = [fix_float(s) for s in latitude]
```

Comment: interesting solution ... probably not great from a performance standpoint but it would certainly do the job

Answer (score 2):

```
def my_float(s):
    s=s.split(".")
    return float(".".join([s[0],"".join(s[1:]))])
```

will split on . and rejoin only adding the first period ... it does not however do anything about `-6.8N`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re  

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d+)\.')
new_lst = [re.sub(pattern, r'\1', i).replace('N', '') for i in latitude]
```

`\d` means any digit, `+` means one or more, `\.` matches the dot character. The parenthesis is capturing that part of the match, and later on in the `sub()` is used as `\1` (meaning first capturing group).

Comment: That works if there is 1 extra period, but not multiple. `'39.04.1450.77.77'` becomes `'39.041450.7777'`.

Comment: @tdelaney Now it removes up to two extra dots. I doubt he needs more than that since he didnt mention it, and since latitude has degrees, minutes and seconds (2 dots max in between).

Comment: The latest still isn't handling `'39.04.1450'`. I think this problem is hard to solve w/ a single pass regular exception and I favor @JoranBeasley's solution. But you bring up a great point - simply removing dots in a degrees.minutes.seconds format doesn't give you the number you want. And suppose its UTM?!

Comment: @tdelaney True, only handles 1 extra dot. But given its latitude i wont try to include other dots, after all. You are correct about his possible problem with conversion from minutes-seconds to degrees.

Answer (score 1):

A small hack if your corrupted data contains only `N` at the end and more than one `.` ... Else you've gotta add more except clauses

```
latitude = [' -86.57', ' 39.04.1450', ' 37.819', ' 45.82', ' 54.42', ' 0.', ' 53.330444', ' +45.75', ' 52.36', ' 43.2167', ' -36.75', ' 6.8N', ' 40.833', ' -97.981', ' 41.720', ' 41.720', ' 37.41', ' 37.41', ' 37.41', ' 37.41']
flist = []
for i in latitude:
    try:
        flist.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        if (i[-1] == 'N'):
            flist.append(float(i[:-1]))
        else:
            flist.append(float("{}.{}".format(i.split(".")[0],''.join(i.split(".")[1:]))))

print (flist)
```

Output

```
[-86.57, 39.04145, 37.819, 45.82, 54.42, 0.0, 53.330444, 45.75, 52.36, 43.2167, -36.75, 6.8, 40.833, -97.981, 41.72, 41.72, 37.41, 37.41, 37.41, 37.41]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to extract the numbers out of the list and convert them to floats right away.

```
import re
lat = lambda l: float(re.search('[+-]*\d*\.\d*',l).group(0))
print map(lat,latitude)
```

edit:
Sorry, I haven't noticed, the digits following second decimal point are also valid. 
A new solution still expects the first dot is OK and all the rest are to be removed.

One of the values contain N, so I suppose there might be also S which means it's southern, i.e. negative latitude. Therefore I implemented this assumption into code.

`def valid_lat(s):
    a = re.findall('\s*[+-]*\d*\.\d*',s)[0]
    b = s.lstrip(a)
    d = b.replace('.','')
    c = re.sub('[nNsS]$','',d)
    sign = 1.
    if re.match('[sS]$',d):sign = -1.
    return (float(a + c))*sign`

Then just `map` it:
`map(valid_lat,latitude)`

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```
def lol_float(_str):
    # check where decimal point is (starting from right) '3.45' -> 2
    dpi = (len(_str) - _str.count('.') - _str.index('.')) if '.' in _str else 0
    # '3.45' -> 345.0
    float_as_int = float(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), _str))
    # dpi = 2, float_as_int = 34.0 -> 3.45
    return float_as_int / (10 ** dpi)
```

Output:

```
>>> lol_float('3.34')
3.34
>>> lol_float('3.45')
3.45
>>> lol_float('345')
345.0
>>> lol_float('34.5')
34.5
>>> lol_float('3.4.5')
3.45
>>> lol_float('3.45')
3.45
>>> lol_float('345')
345.0
>>> lol_float('3.4..5')
3.45
>>> lol_float('3.4..5.4')
3.454
```

Just being original... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any letters using `str.rstrip`:

```
from string import ascii_letters

out = []
for x in latitude:
    x = x.rstrip(ascii_letters)
    spl = x.split(".")
    if len(spl) > 2:
        out.append(float("{}.{}".format(spl[0],"".join(spl[1:]))))
    else:
        out.append(float(x)))
print(out)

[-86.57, 39041450.0, 37.819, 45.82, 54.42, 0.0, 53.330444, 45.75, 52.36, 43.2167, -36.75, 6.8, 40.833, -97.981, 41.72, 41.72, 37.41, 37.41, 37.41, 37.41]
```

You can do it in a single list comp but less efficiently:

```
print([float(x[::-1].rstrip(ascii_letters).replace(".","")[::-1]) if x.count(".") > 1 else float(x.rstrip(ascii_letters)) for x in latitude ])
```